# Switch Teradata Accounts

Tags: sas, teradata

I want to be able to switch between 2 Teradata accounts if the password has expired for one user in SAS.
e.g. connect to teradata (user="&terauser" password="&terapwd" account="&teraacct" server="&tdserver" mode=teradata);

terauser : Password expired
terauser1 : Password valid

Couple of questions:

1. How do I pre-warn the user to change password. Do I use the DBC.Users table.
2. How do I swicth accounts, as I will know the status only in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get connected you can ask Teradata when the password was last changed by querying `DBC.USERSV`.  Then if you know what your expiration rules are you can send a message to the user in the SAS log.  So if you passwords expire after 120 days your query and report might look like this:

```
select catx(' ','%put'
   , case when (days_left < 2) then 'ERROR:'
          when (days_left < 10) then 'WARNING:'
          else 'NOTE:'
     end
   ,'Your Teradata password expires in',days_left,'days.')
 into :tdpassword_message trimmed
from connection to teradata
 (select ((PasswordChgDate+ 120) - date) days_left from dbc.usersV )
;
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------;
* Write message to SAS log ;
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------;
&tdpassword_message;
```

Comment: I cannot seem to access the usersV table. Is this info available elsewhere? kindly help.

Comment: Try the `DBC.USERS` view instead.

Answer (score 1):

Proc SQL maintains some automatic macro variables that you can examine:

```
Proc SQL;
  connect to ....;

  %put NOTE: SQLXRC=%superq(SQLXRC);
  %put NOTE: SQLXMSG=%superq(SQLXMSG);
```

If you want to automatically test and use the working account you could create a macro that performs try connection and switch account behavior.  Be careful about security policies if you put user account info in source code or a plain-text file.

Example:

```
%macro myConnect ();
  %* To be used in the context of a Proc SQL statement;

  %* ... assign first account connection parameters to  macro variables;
  %let terauser=...;
  ...
  %let tdserver = ...;

  connect to teradata (user="&terauser" password="&terapwd" account="&teraacct" server="&tdserver" mode=teradata);

  %if &SQLXRC eq 0 %then %return;

  %* ... assign second account connection parameters to  macro variables;
  %let terauser=...;
  ...
  %let tdserver = ...;

  connect to teradata (user="&terauser" password="&terapwd" account="&teraacct" server="&tdserver" mode=teradata);

  %if &SQLXRC eq 0 %then %return;

  %put ERROR: Could not connect with current connection parameters;
  %abort cancel;
%mend;
```

`Proc SQL` can also connect using existing remote library references:

```
* create remote library references;
libname account1 Teradata ... connection parameters ...;
libname account2 Teradata ... connection parameters ...;

Proc SQL;
  connect using account1;  * connect using the account1
```

Comment: I tried using the macro Sir. Now if I need to write out the credentials to a file how do I do that. When I use pwencode I can write the encrypted password to a file but I need to store the username and password for everyone to call an include statement and use in their code.

Comment: Place the macro, and perhaps a pwencode file, in a network folder that the users have access to.  If you are acting in an admin role, you could privately maintain the macro source code and save only the precompiled encrypted macro to the network folder -- documenation for macro options `SECURE` and `STORE`.  If you have more questions compose a new one, and don't forget to mark which response answered your question (see https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Sir..can I so something similar for Windows authentication for SQL servers. I use SAS in an Unix environment.

Comment: The `myConnect` strategy should work for any `dbms-name`.  Try it and if you have problems create a new question referencing this one.  Be sure to show code, warnings or errors.